# Q: Permission denied when I source .bash_profile

Tags: bash, unix, permission-denied

I'm going through mhartl's Learn Enough Text Editor to be dangerous, and am running into a Permission denied situation when I attempt to execute the bash command...

~$ source .bash_profile

Any idea why?

Comment: What does `ls -la .bash_profile` and `whoami` print?

Answer (score 1):

I've answered my own question:

The tutorial text says to put the contents of Listing 4 into the .bash_profile text file.  Here's Listing 4...

```
Listing 4: Defining a Bash alias.
~/.bash_profile
 alias lr='ls -hartl'
```

Actually, only the last of those three lines should be in the file.  The second line is the location and file name, itself.

If you're reading this, MHARTL, might consider clarifying this...for us noobs.

Comment: To be fair, the box for Listing 4 uses two different colors (although the contrast could be greater), and the first two lines are italicized while the text to enter is not.

Answer (score 1):

`Permission denied` could be because you do not have permission to read `.bash_profile`, or because `.bash_profile` tries to access something to which you do not have access.

If you are able to see the contents `.bash_profile` with :

```
cat .bash_profile
```

then you need to analyse the .bash_profile and see what it is trying to access unsuccessfully, for instance by commenting out commands one by one until you pinpoint which one causes the problem.

If you cannot even read `.bash_profile`, which would be surprising, then you need to figure out why (by using `ls -l .bash_profile` to validate who the owner of the file is, for instance), and correct that problem.